# Accessing selection from jQuery Mobile selection list in another page with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-mobile

I'm building a jQuery Mobile site, using PHP to interact with a MySQL database to dynamically populate the dropdown. Here's the code that creates the first page (a simple selection list within a form, with a submit button):

```
app.php:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page1">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Header
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <form action="showView.php" method="POST">
                <label for="selectmenu1">
                    Select a show:
                </label>
                <select name="selectmenu1" id="select_a_show">
                 <?php 
$con = mysql_connect('tfis.db.7386546.hostedresource.com','tfis','Kurdt4794');

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('tfis', $con);

$queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM Shows';      
$result = mysql_query($queryStr);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $episode_num = $row['episode_num'];
    echo "<option value=" . $episode_num . ">Episode " . $episode_num . "</option>";
} 
mysql_close($con);
?>
        </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I then have a second page to handle the selected value, which I utilize in a PHP query to the database in the following code:

```
showView.php:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
    <body>

<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('tfis.db.7386546.hostedresource.com','tfis','Kurdt4794');

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('tfis', $con);

$episode = $_REQUEST["select_a_show"];
$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Shows WHERE episode_num = $episode LIMIT 1";
echo "Episode" . $episode . $queryStr;
$result = mysql_query($queryStr);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $episode_title = $row['episode_title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    $image_filename = $row['image_filename'];
    $youtube = $row['youtube'];
}
echo "<div data-theme='a' data-role='header'> <h3> " . $episode_title . "</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role='content'>
        <img src='http://foxtechnyc.com/TFIS/images/" . $image_filename . "' />
            </div>
            <div>" . $description . "
            <a data-role='button' data-transition='fade' href='http://foxtechnyc.com/TFIS/audio/" . $filename . "'>
            Listen To Show</a>
            <a data-role='button' data-transition='fade' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" . $youtube . "&feature=player_embedded>
            Watch YouTube Video
            </a></div>";
?>
<script>
    alert(selection);
</script>
</body>
```

The issue is that the value is not being fetched correctly using the following code:

```
$episode = $_REQUEST["select_a_show"];
```

I read up on AJAX long polling from the server, since JQuery is client-side and PHP is server-side but I am unsure how I could implement it here.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I agree. However, I'd like to get something working before I refractor. But thank you...i will revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, the name of your `select` field should be `name="select_a_show"`

In other words, change line 30 in app.php from
    `<select name="selectmenu1" id="select_a_show">`

to
   `<select name="select_a_show" id="select_a_show">`

That should do the trick.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! Such a stupid mistake, but I figured this would be the place to get that "second eye". Many thanks!